# jQuery ui not recognized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Specifically, I have a div container that holds another div, which has its background image set. What I am trying to accomplish is to make a drag/scrollable map, similar to the Google Maps design, minus the zoom ability. In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/gkJaH/11/), there is no flaw in this. My local files, however, do not allow this drag/scroll ability. I use Google's developer links for jQuery/UI and still no avail. Also, I use Dreamweaver CS6 for local development. Any help would be great. Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="drag"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#drag {
width: 1000px;
height: 1100px;
background-image: url(http://www.shepherd.edu/university/visitors/images/campus.jpg);
}

#container {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid green;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#drag').draggable();
})
```

Comment: Before going any further, did you include jquery in your html header?

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Have you checked the console output to see if you're getting 404 errors for Jquery ui etc?

Comment: Yes, they are in the header, checking console now.

Comment: It's referencing: $ not recognized
Interesting seeing as the same CDN is used for the other pages, and works just fine.

Comment: So this worked on my fiddle and my quicktest page in DW, but my full site has been updated and it still refuses to make the image draggable. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/3KqSh/) that is copy of my exact page. Again, any help figuring out why it doesn't allow for the map to move freely, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/gkJaH/11/), is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Feeling really bad about posting this now. Had a thought to check the z-index, and apparently you cannot touch this div that has 'sunk' beneath the rest. Changed links wrapper to z-index of 1 while bringing the body element to an index of 0. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/3KqSh/) to show fix. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your problem, but on the off-chance that it is:

jQuery code will not work without the library being referenced on your page (usually in the `<head>` tags).

Also, there are some other libraries that *build on top of* the jQuery library, like Twitter's excellent [bootstrap library](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), or [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/). In those cases, you need *both* the jQuery library *and* the additional library -- as shown for jQueryUI in the first example below.

There are a few options for including jQuery libraries on your page.

CDNs (Content Delivery Networks) are online storage locations where web pages can grab the specified code, without you needing to store it on your server. [This is why a CDN is a good idea](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

One:  1.  Use a CDN:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```

Two: 2. Download the jQuery script:

- Go here:  http://jquery.com/download/
- Click on the version you want
- When you see the code in your browser, save that into a text file
- It is simplest to just store the jquery.js file in your webroot (usually `public_html`), but you can store it anywhere (and name it anything you want -- you just have to use the same name/location when you reference it in your `<script>` tag.
- Below example has it stored in a subdir called `js`
- Include it in your head tags, thus:

Three: 3. A combination of the above, with **fallback**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

The above code does this:

a.  Load the jQuery library from the CDN
b.  IF the CDN did not load, then load the jQuery from the specified location on *my* server (Note that the jQuery library must also be available on your server, at the location specified).

**Notes:**

- There are two forms of the jquery.js code that you can use: minified and regular. The difference is that the minified code *loads faster*, but the regular code code is human-readable. Use whichever one you wish. If you decide to customize the jQuery library for your own purposes some day, you will want to edit the human-readable one.

Comment: Figured it out. $ and $ui were linked and all the code worked. @gibberish had this originally and realized it must include the 'http:' at the beginning of the CDN address.